# Angular hydration not working with router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router, hydration

I'm trying out the new [hydration](https://angular.io/guide/hydration) feature present in Angular v16 and I can't seem to make it work with routing.

This is my setup:

**app.config.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'hydration',
    component: HydrationComponent,
  }
];
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideHttpClient(), provideClientHydration(), provideRouter(routes)]
};
```

**hydration.component.html:**

```
<p>There are {{ peopleInSpace().length }} people in space right now:</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of peopleInSpace()">
    {{ person.name }} ({{ person.craft }})
  </li>
</ul>
```

**hydration.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-hydration',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './hydration.component.html',
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export default class HydrationComponent implements OnInit {
  spaceService = inject(SpaceService);
  peopleInSpace = signal<Person[]>([]);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.spaceService
      .getPeople()
      .subscribe((result) => this.peopleInSpace.set(result));
  }
}
```

**space.service.ts:**

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  craft: string;
}

@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class SpaceService {
      http = inject(HttpClient);
    
      getPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
        console.log("Requesting data from Open Notify API");
        return this.http
          .get<any>('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json')
          .pipe(map((res) => res.people));
      }
    }
```

If I just render the HydrationComponent directly in the AppComponent:

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-hydration/>
```

then hydration works and:

- I don't see a request to the Open Notify API in the Dev tools
- I see the <script id="ng-state"... tag WITH the cached API data from the server rendering

But if I use router-outlet instead

**app.component.html:**

```
<router-outlet/>
```

And I access /hydration, then

- I see a request to the Open Notify API in the Dev tools
- I see the <script id="ng-state"... tag WITHOUT the cached API data from the server rendering

meaning hydration didn't work properly. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Having had this same issue previously, I believe it may have been caused by [a listed bug in Angular 16](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50562):

> In a new angular 16 app I have found that SSR will not retrieve data in any component other than the app component.

This issue is listed as having been [fixed in Angular version 16.0.5](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/16.0.5), and having run `ng update` to go to this version, the hydration problem no longer occurs for me.